# Explanation for Server 2003 DNS Conditional Forwarding sub-domain behavior

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

I have setup conditional DNS forwarding for certain subdomains but it is behaving in a way that I think is unexpected.

This is what I have setup.

sub1.domain.com -> 1.1.1.1
sub2.domain.com -> 1.1.1.1

Now if anything is going to 
abc.sub1.domain.com it does forward that dns request to 1.1.1.1. However, if there is a domain 123.abc.sub1.domain.com then it does not forward to 1.1.1.1 instead nslookup says that it did not get a response.

However, if I setup another conditional domain rule that says:
abc.sub1.domain.com -> 1.1.1.1

then 123.abc.sub1.domain.com does resolve.

Is this by design? I thought it would act like a wildcard but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding *.sub1.domain.com?  I think you need to explicitly add the wildcard.